# Esconder bombas em um campo minado com ASCII 2

Tags: c

Usando uma matriz bidimensional, crie um programa para implementar um jogo de campo minado. Para preencher as posições da matriz, use números aleatórios de modo que 0 represente uma posição livre e 1 uma bomba. O usuário deve poder cometer 3 erros. Posições escolhidas livres devem ser marcadas por (ASCII 2); posições com bombas já escolhidas devem ser marcadas (ASCII 15) e as posições não marcadas devem ser marcadas com (ASCII 63).

Como faço pra esconder as posições das casas com as figura (ASCII 2)?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define tam 10

int matri[tam][tam];

void forma()
{
    int i, e;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        for(e=0; e<10; e++)
        {
            matri[e][i]= rand()%2;
        }
    }
}

void mostra()
{
    int i, e;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        for(e=0; e<10; e++)
        {
            printf("%3d",matri[e][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
//
void jogar()
{

    int L,C, erros=0;
    char a = 2, b = 15;
    do
    {
        printf("\n\n linha L ?");
        scanf("%d", &L);
        printf("\n\n coluna C ?");
        scanf("%d", &C);

        if(matri[L][C] = 0)
        {
            matri[L][C] = a;
        }
        else if(matri[L][C] = 1)
        {
            erros++;
            matri[L][C] = b;
        }
    }
    while(erros = 3);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    forma();
    mostra();
    esconde();
    jogar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A imagem que colocou não está a funcionar. Aproveite e explique melhor a sua duvida. Qual parte não está a conseguir fazer e o que já tentou para a a fazer

Comment: a imagem era da pergunta da questao. que adicionei

Comment: duvida é como faço pra esconde as posiçoes das casas com as figura (ANCII 2)

Comment: Separe a camada de apresentação da camada de representação. A representação lógica da bomba deve ser tratada como um terreno desconhecido

Comment: O problema é que vai precisar de mais lógica para saber o que o usuário já escolheu. Se a matriz bidimensional tem apenas os livres(0) e bombas(1), você não tem forma de saber quais o utilizador já escolheu para mostrar ou esconder bombas

Comment: Também ajuda o fato de separar o mapa de terreno explorado do terreno real. Como se fosse aplicar um _fog of war_ mesmo CLI

Comment: tente não usar os caracteres de código entre 0 e 31 - eles são "não imprimíveis". Alguns, como 0x0a (10) e 0x0d (13) tem comportamento bem definido na impressão, mas não é o caso para outros.  ASCII é de 32 até 127.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em `C`, para comparar a igualdade entre dois valores inteiros é necessário usar o operador de igualdade `==`. Você está usando o operador de atribuição `=` em suas comparações e isso não vai funcionar como você espera.

Para resolver seu problema, você pode criar uma matriz auxiliar para fazer o controle da exibição do seu campo minado.

O enunciado fala sobre uns códigos ASCII não printáveis tais como `2` e `15`, isto está correto ?

Se eu entendi bem a ideia, segue seu código modificado, comentado e testado para que o seu jogo fique "vivo":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define tam 10

#define BOMBA           'B'      /* ASCII 66 (Deveria ser ASCII 15) */
#define LIVRE           '?'      /* ASCII 63 (OK)*/
#define ESCOLHIDA       ' '      /* ASCII 32 (Deveria ser ASCII 2) */

int matri[tam][tam];      /* Mapeamento das bombas  */
int tabuleiro[tam][tam];  /* Tabuleiro somente para exibicao na tela */

void forma()
{
    int i, e;

    srand(time(NULL));     /* O gerador de numeros aleatorios
                             inicializado com uma semente baseada
                             na hora local do computador */
    for(i=0; i<tam; i++)
    {
        for(e=0; e<tam; e++)
        {
            matri[e][i] = rand() % 2;
            tabuleiro[e][i] = LIVRE;    /* Inicializa tabuleiro com celula livre */
        }
    }
}

void mostra()
{
    int i, e;
    for(i=0; i<tam; i++)
    {
        for(e=0; e<tam; e++)
        {
            printf("%3c",tabuleiro[e][i]); /* Exibe tabuleiro */
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int vitoria()
{
    int i, e;
    for(i=0; i<tam; i++)
    {
        for(e=0; e<tam; e++)
        {
            if( tabuleiro[e][i] == LIVRE ) /* Verifica se exista alguma celula livre no tabuleiro */
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;  /* Nenhuma celula livre */
}

int jogar()
{
    int L,C, erros=0;

    /* Antes de jogar, inicializa campo minado */
    forma();

    while(1)
    {
        mostra(); /* Exibe tabuleiro a cada rodada */

        printf("Linha? ");
        scanf("%d", &L);
        printf("Coluna? ");
        scanf("%d", &C);

        if(matri[L][C] == 0) /* Celula sem bomba */
        {
            tabuleiro[L][C] = ESCOLHIDA;  /* Ajusta tabuleiro */

            if(vitoria()) /* Verifica Vitoria */
                return 1;   /* Venceu! */
        }
        else if(matri[L][C] == 1) /* Celula com bomba */
        {
            erros++;
            tabuleiro[L][C] = BOMBA;   /* Ajusta Tabuleiro */

            printf("\nBOMBA EXPLODIU! (%d de 3)\n\n", erros );

            if( erros >= 3 ) /* Verifica fim de jogo */
                return 0;   /* Fim de Jogo! */
        }

    }
}


int main(void)
{
    if(jogar())
    {
        printf("Parabens! Voce venceu!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Voce Perdeu! Game Over!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Por curiosidade, o que o `printf("%3c")` faz? Não sei o que o modificador 3 faz ao lado do `c`, só usei ele para questões numéricas, nunca de caracter

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado: Acredito ser o `placeholder` opcional chamado `Width Filed`, que representa a quantidade *mínima* de caracteres na saída, no caso, o `%3c` coloca 2 espaços a frente do caractere. Segue referência: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Format_placeholder_specification

Answer (score 0):

Pela execução do seu programa a matriz tem só 0's e 1's, mas o campo minado precisa ter a quantidade de bombas que tem ao lado de uma casa vazia, que são no máximo 8 (tinha colocado errado) bombas para qualquer índice no meio da matriz, 5 para as bordas e 3 para os cantos.
O melhor de ser fazer é criar uma matriz auxiliar indicando que tudo está vazio, enquanto o usuário ainda não tenho escolhido nenhuma casa.
Quando ele escolhe a casa você reconstrói a matriz pegando o que tem na posição e ao lado dela, caso seja uma bomba o programa acaba.

A matriz auxilixar vai ter as bombas e a quantidade de bombas nas casas sem bomba.

Comment: A quantidade de vizinhança com bombas é 8 no máximo. Logicamente só precisa dessa informação  binária, a vizinhança poderia ser calculada _on the fly_, mas pré calculá-la daria uma boa economia de tempo de execução

Comment: essa é a duvida... como faço isso?